# HTML5 CSS style issue

Tags: css, html

Can't get my div tag css working  Can somebody please point out the mistake I am making here.  Trying to have one div take 70% of the page (left, top to bottom), the other two divs share the remainder.  Added colour just so I can see if correct but not showing at all.

```css
#master {
  width: 70%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: orange
}

#detail1 {
  top: 0;
  left: 70%;
  background: blue
}

#detail2 {
  top: 50%;
  left: 70%;
  background: green
}
```

```html
<header>
</header>

<div id="master"></div>
<div id="detail1"></div>
<div id="detail2"></div>

<aside>
  Hello Ben
</aside>

<footer>
</footer>
```

Comment: Your empty divs have no content or height. You also didn't set a position on them so `top` and `left` won't do anything.

Comment: `top` and `left` are used for positioned elements (i.e. `position:absolute;`). None of your divs are positioned.

Answer (score 2):

Add height to your divs

```css
#master {
  width: 70%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: orange;
      height: 15px;
}

#detail1 {
  top: 0;
  left: 70%;
  background: blue;
      height: 15px;
}

#detail2 {
  top: 50%;
  left: 70%;
  background: green;
      height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<header>
</header>

<div id="master"></div>
<div id="detail1"></div>
<div id="detail2"></div>

<aside>
  Hello Ben
</aside>

<footer>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your `div` blocks (master, detail1, detail2) are empty they won't show at all. Enter some content or set a height via css `height` attribute.

Comment: I added back colour and tried to size them as explained.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that to solve your problem, you have to add position to your css. What is more to get master div from top to bottom height should be define as width for details to use rest of screen space. Like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>My new Page II</title>
    <style>
        #master{
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width:70%;            
            height: 100%;

            background: orange
        }
        #detail1{
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;            
            left: 70%;
            height: 50%;
            width: 30%;
            background: blue
        }

        #detail2{
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;            
            left: 70%;
            height: 50%;
            width: 30%;
            background: green
        } 
    </style> 
</head> 
<body>
    <header>
    </header>

    <div id="master"></div>
    <div id="detail1"></div>
    <div id="detail2"></div>

    <aside>
        Hello Ben
    </aside>

    <footer>
    </footer> </body> </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the height of div block.